# Does $\mathbf{Tos}$ generate $\mathbf{DLat}$ as a variety?

Tags: universal-algebra

Let $\mathbf{DLat}$ denote the variety of distributive lattices and let $\mathbf{Tos}$ denote the subclass of $\mathbf{DLat}$ consisting of the totally-ordered sets.

> **Question.** Does $\mathbf{Tos}$ generate $\mathbf{DLat}$ as a variety?

Comment: Definitely, even the 2-element chain does

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf, you seem to be right, by proposition 3 [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139810/embedding-a-brouwerian-lattice-into-a-boolean-lattice).

Comment: Glad you found a reference.